# Kali disconnect from WiFi when tools are used

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, airmon-ng, airodump-ng

My kail linux (desktop dual boot, not vm) disconnects from WiFi whenever I do something with the given tools. It works fine with the browser and even other terminal procedures like vim. However, when I try to use a tool like wifite, arimon-ng or airodump-ng, it disconnects. After it disconnects, the adapter can no longer find any networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-Hello! this ends up happening just because unfortunately the use of some tools mainly airmon-ng or other tools that make use of the network device is this very thing, why they need access to a network device "card" even to create addresses the virtual items of the tools in use, so the fall of the internet connection is normal, if you want to continue to have access, use the internet access during this process you need to have another network device to do it! or reset the changes that you have made it like, mac-address changing, and others...

Answer (score -1):

I've had this problem many times when it comes to using `wifite`, `airo*-ng`, `fluxion`, where it will disconnect my wlan0 (connected to regular AP serving inet) when the apps are launched.. I'm working on a definite fix.  But for now, experiment with this method:

Get famliar with the CLI tools `iw`, `iwconfig`, `ifconfig`, `wpa_supplicant`, `wpa_passphrase`.

Get unfamliar with `nm-applet` (the wifi gui connection app in top task bar)

This has worked for me in the past:

Prior to starting `wifite` or any of the haxing tools above:

```
service network-manager stop
killall wpa_supplicant
killall dhclient
ps guax | grep wpa   # verify there are no other rogue wpa_* proc. running
```

start your attack (in your lab of course) with `wifite` or `fluxion`

one that is initiated, manually connect to your AP:

in another term:

```
wpa_passphrase <SSID> <PW>  > /etc/wpa_ssid.conf
ifconfig wlan0 up
wpa_supplicant -i wlan0  -c /etc/wpa_ssid.conf
<in another term once that connects>
```

verify your associated with `iwconfig wlan0`
if so:

```
dhclient wlan0
```